# Reading data from FIFO as it arrives (linux)

Tags: c, linux, ipc, pipe, fifo

I have two programs written in C. Program A generates output to FIFO and program B reads that output from FIFO and decides to process accordingly. Now in program A, I have redirected stdout to FIFO so that every printf method throws output to the FIFO.

In program B, I am opening the FIFO (in read mode) and start reading output of process A from it line by line with fgets(). Now problem arises here as the behaviour which I expected is not what I get.

I expected that as soon as process A prints some line to FIFO, process B should should get it instantly (like a live update of what is happening in process A) but what I get is that content in FIFO is not read in process B until process A closes the FIFO connection because of which I get data in bulk instead of having it as soon as process A prints something to FIFO.

I want to know whether it is default behaviour of FIFO (i.e. data is read in bulk when writing end closes the connection)?

I wish I had code at this moment but I am posting this from my home computer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you call `fflush` in program A?

Comment: you have to use fflush first when process B goes to read the FIFO to make sure that all buffered data are writeen before read happens.

Comment: Alternatively, set the stream to be unbuffered with `setbuf`.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I havent called fflush. I'll try it and provide feedback there after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised in comments to my question, I used fflush in program A and it solved the problem. Thanks all of above.